# Data-table Cell value update not work

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, datatables

I have two datatable in two different bootstrap tab. My first datatable is

```
var table = $('#adjustment-table').DataTable();
```

This table have two input box in every row named area and fine.
When user put any value in area or fine then second table same row same column cell display that value.

Second table is

```
var run_table=$('#run-table').DataTable();
```

I am trying this way

```
    $(document).on('keydown', '.areaField', function(){

        var rowId=$(this).attr('data-area-id');

        var value=$(this).val();
        run_table
            .cell(rowId, 0)
            .data(value)
            .draw(true);

    });
```

when user give any value then it show in second value.Like I am typing in row one column 3  input box and give value is 10
then #run-table row one column 3 display 10

But this doesn't work. Can somebody explain the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You always updating second table variable `run_table`, instead you need to find which table row get updated.
See below code -

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.areaField', function(){

        var rowId=$(this).attr('data-area-id');
        var cell_id=cell( this ).index();
        var value=$(this).val();
        var $parentTable = $(this).closest('table');
        var tableId = $parentTable.attr('id');
        if(tableId == 'adjustment-table')
        {
           table
            .cell(rowId, 0)
            .data(value)
            .draw(true);
         } 
         else 
         {
              run_table
            .cell(rowId, 0)
            .data(value)
            .draw(true);
         }
        alert(pos);
    });
```